# Grab all rows columns in table apart from rows which have a non-unique value in one column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I understand that if I use something like:
`SELECT DISTINCT product_id FROM products;`

It will return the product_id column with unique values. However if I want to return the other columns from the table as well, is `DISTINCT` still the best approach?

Or is a group by statement more appropriate?

(I'm using Postgres)

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected result in the form of text as part of an edit so we can understand better.

Comment: Please share sample data and required output.

Comment: Neither of your questions make sense.  If three records share a common value, then you need to tell us what the logic is for choosing _which_ of the other column values you want to include.  Sample data would really help here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SELECT DISTINCT ON (product_id) * FROM products`

That will return rows with distinct `product_id`, and return all columns of those rows.

If you care about the data in those other columns (e.g. you want the latest row for each product_id, rather than just random rows), you should also include an order:

`SELECT DISTINCT ON (product_id) * FROM products ORDER BY product_id, [other fields]`